# Accessing glassfish server from Android, emulator

Tags: android, glassfish, emulation

I have glassfish running on the laptop. How can I access it from a real android device or an emulator

Comment: Open up a socket or an HTTP connection to your ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it using an HTTPURLConnection you have simply:

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ( new URL(url)).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
```

Remember that if you use your emulator localhost (127.0.0.1) corresponds to 10.0.2.2.
Once you have your connection open you can read and write using InputStream or Outpustream.

If you use a real device be sure your glashfish server is visible from your smartphone.